# Database and tables

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, html-table

I've got some issues with a table and inserting data in it.

I want to get 2 rows of information next to eachother from 2 different tables. ButI can't figure it out to get 2 seperated rows for each table. Below you can find my code:

```
<form action="Stap5.php" method="POST">
    <table border = '1'>
        <tr>
             <td>Vloerbetegeling</td>
             <td>Wandbetegeling</td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    $query="select * from vloertegel";
    $result=mysql_query($query);

    $query2="select * from wandtegel";
    $result2=mysql_query($query2);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?>
        <tr>
        <td><input type='radio' name='FloorTiles' value='<?php echo  $row['Naam'] ?>' checked/><?php echo  $row['Naam'] ?> <br/>
        <img src='<?php echo $row['ImagePath'] ?>' width='200' height='200' /> </td>
        </tr>
    <?php            
    }
    while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
    ?>
        <tr>
        <td><input type='radio' name='WallTiles' value='<?php echo $row2['Naam'] ?>'checked/> <?php echo $row2['Naam'] ?> <br/> 
        <img src='<?php echo $row2['ImagePath'] ?>' width='200' height='200'/></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" name="Stap5Submit" value="Volgende"/><br />
</form>
```

The while loops are making it harder to get my result.

Comment: and your problem is? Also: mysql_* functions are deprecated, please use mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: Well, I get 1 row now. They are all below each other. I want 2 different rows. 1 for WallTiles, 1 for FloorTiles

Comment: What's not working? What happens? Do you get any errors?

Comment: and there is data in both tables?

Comment: Can you post the resulting HTML generated by the script?

Comment: Here I have a link: http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/5039/b6bt.png  When the image changes it needs to split into a 2nd row.

Comment: @ScottHelme how can I do that? I'm pretty new to php. Working with it for half a year now.

Comment: Just view the source on the page it creates and add the relevant HTML so we can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be nicer to have all tiles in 1 table?

```
table tiles: (id, name, imagePath, tileType);

// to fetch all tiles:
SELECT * FROM tiles ORDER BY tileType
```

Then you only have to do 1 query, and 1 loop

```
<?php 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="<?php 
               ($row["tileType"] == 'xxx') ? 'FloorTiles': 'WallTiles'; ?>" ?> 
               value="<?php echo  $row['name'] ?>" checked/><?php 
                   echo  $row['name'] 
               ?> <br/>
        <img src="<?php echo $row['imagePath'] ?>" width="200" height="200" />
    </td>
</tr>
<?php            
}
?>
```

Comment: Well the point is that I want to get 2 rows. 1 for Floortiles 1 for Walltiles. If I use ur code I get 1 row with all the tiles in it.

Comment: No, it will produce an HTML row for each row in the database.

Comment: Well I'm not allowed to change anything in the Database so, I can't edit these tables